# Check validity of datetime?

Tags: python, datetime

I would like to create a setter method for a datetime object so that I can customize the `replace` method. Is this possible?

For example:

```
datetime = datetime.replace(day = 34)
```

This throws an error because `34` is not a valid number of days for any month, but what I would like to do is increase the month by `1` and then subtract `28`, `30`, or `31` days.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your need?! month + 1 - 31 days ??

Comment: He'd like to make `day=34` equivalent to `day=replacementDay; while (day > daysPerMonth(month)) {day=day-daysPerMonth(month);month+=1;}`.  In other words, treating an invalid day number as simply farther into the future than the current month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass `datetime` and provide your own implementation of the `replace` method.

Answer (score 1):

this doesn't answer your question directly, but if you're just trying to increment the datetime object, you can use timedelta.  For example:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

datetime(2011, 1, 1) + timedelta(days=34)
```

Comment: Great solution - would have worked for everything except setting days exactly rather than incrementing them